# How to do server to server publish/subscribe?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

**I want to do:**

I have a mongodb in server A and a mongodb in server B, I want server B's mongodb can subscribe to server A's publish.

Means, server B's mongodb is a subset of server A's mongodb.

It can be any other database.

Is there any tech(database/framework/libs) can do this?

**Original:**

What I found is 
Meteor works with server publish and client subscribe.

But what I need to do is a server to server publish/subscribe, does meteor support this?

Comment: This feels like an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clearly state the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the solution (using pub/sub on the server)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon updated

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you want to do this? Perhaps there is a different solution to your problem. (And I am just curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment variables for meteor. Here is example;

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://serverB:8000/db_name
```